# Why have I not gotten Peer Pressure badge after deleting my posts?

Tags: discussion, badges

I didn't get my badge for deleting my posts, a [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205604/96277) and an [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205605/96277) to the same question.  I deleted both the post and I was supposed to get a badge but I don't see it so far.

Comment: I assume you mean [Peer Pressure](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/peer-pressure) badge? Could you link to your deleted post?

Answer (score 4):

Until they were deleted, your question had net 0 votes and your answer to that question had net -1 votes. To get [Peer Pressure](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/peer-pressure) badge, your post must have -3 votes at least.

Now I wouldn't encourage you to get this badge by making low quality posts. That badge is something that must not be a goal of anybody here. If you're into badges, there are [plenty of them](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/badges) which requires positive contribution to this website and are easy to get. Ideally, we hope that users contribute to this site without explicitly aiming for badges only.